# Status of in-place `rfft` and `irfft` in Julia

Tags: fft, julia, fftw

So I'm doing some hobby-related stuff which involves taking Fourier transforms of large real arrays which barely fit in memory, and was curious to see if there was an in-place version of `rfft` and `irfft` that saved RAM, since RAM consumption is important to me. [These transforms are possible despite the input-vs-output-type mismatch](http://fftw.org/doc/Multi_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html#Multi_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data), and require an extra row of padding.

In [Implement in-place rfft! and irfft!](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/6180), Tim Holy said he was working on an in-place `rfft!` and `irfft!` that made use of a buffer-containing `RCpair` object, but then Steven Johnson said that he was implementing something equivalent using `A_mul_B!(y, plan, x)`, which he elaborated on [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/6193).

Things get a little weird from then on. In the documentation for both [0.3.0](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/base/?highlight=a_mul_b#Base.A_mul_B) and [0.4.0](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/?highlight=a_mul_b#Base.A_mul_B) there is no mention of `A_mul_B!`, although `A_mul_B` is listed. But when I try entering them into Julia, I get

```
A_mul_B!
A_mul_B! (generic function with 28 methods)

A_mul_B
ERROR: A_mul_B not defined
```

which suggests that the situation is actually the *opposite* of what the documentation currently describes.

So since `A_mul_B!` seems to exist, but isn't documented anywhere, I tried to guess how to test it in-place as follows:

```
A = rand(Float32, 10, 10);
p = plan_rfft(A);
A_mul_B!(A,p,A)
```

which resulted in

```
ERROR: `A_mul_B!` has no method matching A_mul_B!(::Array{Float32,2}, ::Function, ::Array{Float32,2})
```

So...

1. Are in-place real FFTs still a work in progress? Or am I using `A_mul_B!` wrong?
2. Is there a mismatch between the 0.3.0 documentation and 0.3.0's function library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That pull request from Steven Johnson is listed as open, not merged; that means the work hasn't been finished yet. The one from me is closed, but if you want the code you can grab it by clicking on the commits.

The docs indeed omit mention of `A_mul_B!`. `A_mul_B` is equivalent to `A*B`, and so isn't exported independently now. `A_mul_B!` would be used like this: instead of `C = A*B`, you could say `A_mul_B!(C, A, B)`.

Can you please edit the docs to fix these issues? (You can edit files [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/tree/master/doc/stdlib) in your webbrowser.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and see if I can figure out how to use your `RCpair` tomorrow, although I'll probably have questions because I'm a terrible programmer and get confused pretty easily. I'd certainly love to help patch up the documentation and any other non-development related stuff, as I actually enjoy helping out with that sort of thing. Just to clarify, do you want me to remove the entry for `A_mul_B` and add an entry explaining the use of `A_mul_B!`?